# Cerrar Formulario Abrir un nuevo Formulario c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Buenas noches quisiera que me ayuden.

Soy nuevo en c# y quisiera que me ayuden estoy realizando un login pero cuando entre quiero que entre a otro formulario y se cierre el formulario que se logeo

Este es el codigo actual :

```
private void btnIngresar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (txtUsuario.Text.Trim() == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ingrese el Usuario", "Aviso del Sistema");
        }
        else if (txtpassword.Text.Trim() == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ingrese su Password", "Aviso del Sistema");
        }
        else
        {
            obj.Alu_Usuario = txtUsuario.Text;
            obj.Alu_llave = txtpassword.Text;
            obj.Opc = 1;

            string resP = Cls_N_Alumno.ConsultarLogin(obj).Rows[0][0].ToString();

            if (resP == "1")
            {
                txtpassword.Text = "";
                txtUsuario.Text = "";
                MessageBox.Show("Usuario Correctos", "Aviso del Sistema");
                FrmMenu frm = new FrmMenu();
                frm.Show();
                this.Close();



            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error Login", "Aviso del Sistema");
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Tu codigo parece correcto. Que problema tienes con el? Alguna excepcion?

Answer (score 4):

No deberias tener que cerrar ningun form cuando realzias un login, porque se supone que este form de autenticacion lo implementas antes de asignar el `Application.Run()`

Si defines el form de login dentro del `Main()` que esta en `Program.cs` puedes autenticar y luego indicar cual es el form principal

Esto lo explico en el articulo

[Login – Usando Password con Hash](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2010/05/login-usando-password-con-hash.html)

[[Winform] Realizar tareas antes de inicializar aplicación](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2009/09/c-winforms-realizar-tareas-antes-de.html)

analiza como se muestra el dilogo de login y acto seguido si la auntenticacion es correcta se abre el form principal, pero sin tener que ocultar ningun form

Answer (score 0):

Cuando el login es correcto, puedes cerrar el actual y abrir otro de la siguiente manera:

```
Hide(); //Oculta el formulario actual
menu formMenu = new menu(); //creamos instancia del Formulario Menú
formMenu.Show(); //abrimos el nuevo Formulario
```

Answer (score 0):

De esta manera puedes minimizar el formulario actual e ir a otro, puedes adaptar este ejemplo a tu inconveniente.

```
private void btn_VolverAlRegistro_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Empleados frm = new Empleados();

            frm.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
```

Toma en cuenta:
***Empleados*** es el nombre del formulario al que quiero ir.

Espero de alguna manera que funcione para futuras visitas a esta pregunta.